# How to print in the same line as a progress in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to print the text in the following manner

```
Waiting for completion.
Waiting for completion..
Waiting for completion...
```

[Note :Not more than three dots]

The above should be in the same line and in a loop.

When the loop condition is false I want to get the following in the same line as well :

```
Waiting for completion... [OK]
```

How do I achieve this in bash script?

Comment: How are you running the script? and what is the condition determining the finish of executon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use carriage return. Search information in echo about \r.

for example maybe you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 3 -gt 2 ];
do
    echo -n -e 'Esperando.\r'
    sleep 1
    echo -n -e 'Esperando..\r'
    sleep 1
    echo -n -e 'Esperando...\r'
    sleep 1
    echo -n -e '             \r'
done
```

You need to sleep cause if you dont sleep you won't be able to watch the changing dots.

Comment: Getting Waiting for completion... on third iteration and then no change is happening

Comment: Okey, sorry I didn't understand you, maybe this is what you need. Look my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c()
{
    flag=1
}

dots()
{
    if [ "$1" -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo .
    fi
    if [ "$1" -eq 2 ]
    then
    echo ..
    fi
    if [ "$1" -eq 3 ]
    then
    echo ...
    fi
}


flag=0

dots_count=1

while [ "$flag" -eq 0 ]
do
    if [ "$dots_count" -eq 4 ]
    then
    dots_count=1
    fi

    printf "\r%sWaiting for completion%s" "$(tput el)" "$(dots "$dots_count")"
    dots_count=$((dots_count + 1))
    sleep 1
done



printf "\r%sWaiting for completion... [OK]\n" "$(tput el)"
```

It will continuously print `Waiting for completion` followed by up to
three dots in the same line.  When <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> is
pressed then `"Waiting for completion... [OK]"` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Use echo's "-n" switch

next echo will print on the same line